# Complexity of a nested for loop over n and an exact integer?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am wondering how one would find the Big-Oh complexity of an algorithm if the for loops loop over both n *and* some specified integer. For example, what would be the complexity of a function such as this one:

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < 100; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k < n; k++) {
            // Some O(1) operation here.
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know that both the outer and most-inner for loops have complexity O(n), but what is the complexity of the middle loop? O(100), would that reduce to O(1)?

Comment: Yes `O(C)` where `C` is some constant is equivalent to `O(1)`. Overall that is just `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be `O(1)` for the middle one only. That means no matter what my input `n` is it doesn't matter it will run 100 times. You can't make it loop more.

But the outermost and inner most they are dependent on `n`. If n is 100 then ouermost runs 100 times if it is 1000000 then yes it runs 1000000 times.

What about inner most loop. For each iteration of outermost it runs 100*n times. So in total it will run even more 100*n*n times.

Now think how much total work they do?

`100n^2+100n+n = An^2+B`

`O(n^2)` will be the time complexity.

#### Is O(10) or O(100) and O(100000) same?

Okay I will save you  from writing more for any Constant `C` O(C) is equivalent to `O(1)`.

Here C was 10 or 100 or 100000.